# Apache Beam Kafka IO for Json messages - org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, kafka-consumer-api, apache-beam

Am trying to get familiar with Apache beam Kafka IO and getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:348)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:318)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:213)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:303)
    at com.andrewjones.KafkaConsumerExample.main(KafkaConsumerExample.java:58)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
```

Following is piece of code which reads messages from a kafka topic. Appreciate if you someone can provide some pointers.

public class KafkaConsumerJsonExample {
static final String TOKENIZER_PATTERN = "[^\p{L}]+";

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

    // Create the Pipeline object with the options we defined above.
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    p.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()
            .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
            .withTopic("myTopic2")
            .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
            .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)

            .updateConsumerProperties(ImmutableMap.of("auto.offset.reset", (Object)"earliest"))

            // We're writing to a file, which does not support unbounded data sources. This line makes it bounded to
            // the first 5 records.
            // In reality, we would likely be writing to a data source that supports unbounded data, such as BigQuery.
            .withMaxNumRecords(5)

            .withoutMetadata() // PCollection<KV<Long, String>>
    )
            .apply(Values.<String>create())

            .apply(TextIO.write().to("wordcounts"));
    System.out.println("running data pipeline");
    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by using `LongDeserializer` for keys that seems were serialised by other serialiser than Long and it depends how you produced the records.

So, you either can use a proper deserializer or, if keys don't matter, as a workaround, try to use `StringDeserializer` for keys as well.

Comment: Great to hear that!